# Crear un script partiendo de un archivo muestra, para cada día de la semana

Tags: array, linux, awk

Hola debo crear un archivo que partiendo de unos datos me muestre, para cada día de la semana, el tanto por ciento de vuelos retrasados, el total de vuelos retrasados y el total de vuelos. Los vuelos retrasados son aquellos que en el campo DEP_DEL15 (sexta columna) contienen el valor 1.

```
"DAY_OF_MONTH","DAY_OF_WEEK","ORIGIN","DEST","DEP_TIME","DEP_DEL15","CANCELLED","DIVERTED","DISTANCE"
1,Tuesday,ORD,GRB,1003,0.00,0.00,0.00,322.248
1,Tuesday,TUL,ORD,1027,0.00,0.00,0.00,1083.42
1,Tuesday,EWR,TYS,1848,0.00,0.00,0.00,1168.61
1,Tuesday,BTR,IAH,1846,0.00,0.00,0.00,468.556
1,Tuesday,RIC,IAH,1038,0.00,0.00,0.00,2142.76
1,Tuesday,OMA,IAH,0555,0.00,0.00,0.00,1446.41
6,Sunday,RSW,LGA,1350,1.00,0.00,0.00,2000.16
6,Sunday,LGA,RSW,0807,0.00,0.00,0.00,2000.16
6,Sunday,LGA,BOS,1856,0.00,0.00,0.00,340.768
6,Sunday,RDU,BOS,1950,0.00,0.00,0.00,1133.42
6,Sunday,IND,LGA,1720,0.00,0.00,0.00,1222.32
```

Actualmente aplicando lo que he hecho me salen las columnas total de vuelos retrasados y el tanto por ciento de ellos, pero no  se como añadir la tercera columna que es el total de vuelos.

En este programa me limito solo a los que registros que tienen vuelos retrasados pero claro debo para la otra columna poner el numero total de todos los vuelos. Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

NR>1 {if ($6==1)
{
    a[$2]++
  count++}
}

END { 
    for (i in a) {
        b[a[i],i] = i
    }

    n = asorti(b)

    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        split (b[i], c, SUBSEP)
        d[++x] = c[2]
    }
    
    for (j=1;j<=n;j++) {
        print d[j], a[d[j]],(a[d[j]]/count)*100
    }
 }
```

Comment: ¿cuál debería ser la salida para este fichero de entrada?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es lo que estás buscando. He simplificado algo el código que tú tenías.

Tenemos tres arrays asociativos cuyo índice será el nombre del día:
v - contendrá el número total de vuelos por día
vr - contendrá el número total de vuelos retrasados por día
dias_ordenado - contendrá los índices empleados en vr ordenados

El formato de salida final será
NOMBRE_DIA RETRASADOS TOTALES PORCENTAJE_RETRASADOS

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

NR > 1 {

    v[$2]++

    if ($6 == 1) {
        vr[$2]++
    }

}

END { 
    
    n = asorti(vr, dias_ordenado)    
    
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        dia = dias_ordenado[i]
        print dia, vr[dia], v[dia], (vr[dia] * 100) / v[dia]
    }

}
```

Aplicando este script a tus datos de ejemplo obtendríamos

```
Sunday 1 5 20
Tuesday 2 6 33.3333
```

En tus cálculos estás determinando el porcentaje de aviones retrasados respecto al total de retrasados en todos los días (count). Me parece que esto no es del todo correcto si estamos empleando para agrupar el día.

Comment: Si es correcto, es lo que necesitaba gracias.